# Hwo do I display the output of a javascript function through HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to create a calculator for a formula. This function works, I have seen in the console. I just can't figure out how to display the output.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NhJ3.jpg)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Take a look at these, innerHTML for change of HTML code in your page, or innerText for changing the text only:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp and https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_innertext.asp

Answer (score 1):

Here it goes;
Like the comment said there are different way and all depends on your context and UI.

Here is quick possibility how you can take your own code forward to show html;

[DOM Inner HTML property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp)

I have just used a button to trigger the function with runs your calculation function and then updates the div that we predefined. This part could be any thing for that matter.

```js
function add(a,b){

return a+b;

}


console.log(add(1,4));


var displayhtml = document.querySelector('div');
var trigger = document.querySelector('button');

trigger.onclick = function (){
displayhtml.innerHTML = add(1,4); 
}
```

```html
<div>I am div</div>

<button>chnage html</button>
```